# If condition always true for ValidateUser method in custom Membership provider

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have created a custom membership provider for SharePoint FBA. In the ValidateUser method, i am verifying the username and password. **The problem is that login is verified even if the password doesn't match. The If condition for password returns true in all cases.**

```
  if (user != null)
            {


               if(password==pass)
                {

                    return true;

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            else

                return false;
```

I have tried password.equals and string.compare methods also but got the same result.